# I have included all the dependencies in POM.xml, I am getting symbol not found error while "mvn install"

Tags: maven, rest-assured

I am new to maven. Please help! Even if I have included all the dependencies in POM.xml, I am getting symbol not found error while "mvn install".

Here is the complete stack trace for your reference-

```
 mvn install                                                                                        ✔  7s   02:45:00 PM  ▓▒░
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< org.example:RestAssuredTest >---------------------
[INFO] Building RestAssuredTest 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ RestAssuredTest ---
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ RestAssuredTest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/mukulsharma/IdeaProjects/RestAssuredTest/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ RestAssuredTest ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/mukulsharma/IdeaProjects/RestAssuredTest/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ RestAssuredTest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/mukulsharma/IdeaProjects/RestAssuredTest/target/test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/mukulsharma/IdeaProjects/RestAssuredTest/src/test/java/myFirstRestAssuredClass.java:[1,1] package io.restassured.RestAssured does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/mukulsharma/IdeaProjects/RestAssuredTest/src/test/java/myFirstRestAssuredClass.java:[2,1] package io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/mukulsharma/IdeaProjects/RestAssuredTest/src/test/java/myFirstRestAssuredClass.java:[3,1] package org.hamcrest.Matchers does not exist
[INFO] 3 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.642 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-02T14:45:12+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project RestAssuredTest: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/mukulsharma/IdeaProjects/RestAssuredTest/src/test/java/myFirstRestAssuredClass.java:[1,1] package io.restassured.RestAssured does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/mukulsharma/IdeaProjects/RestAssuredTest/src/test/java/myFirstRestAssuredClass.java:[2,1] package io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/mukulsharma/IdeaProjects/RestAssuredTest/src/test/java/myFirstRestAssuredClass.java:[3,1] package org.hamcrest.Matchers does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Could you add pom.xml to the question?

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree` and check the dependency is in the tree.